# Why getch() is throwing an error in C

Tags: c, keyboard, codeblocks, arrow-keys

I am running a C program in Code :: Blocks in windows XP.
I am getting an error as

```
"drawing operation is attempeted when there was no current window"
```

What might cause this and how can I solve it?
My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
static int get_code(void);
// System dependent key codes
enum
{
    KEY_ESC     = 27,
    ARROW_UP    = 256 + 72,
    ARROW_DOWN  = 256 + 80,
    ARROW_LEFT  = 256 + 75,
    ARROW_RIGHT = 256 + 77
};
int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    puts("Press arrow keys, escape key + enter to exit:");
    while (( ch = get_code()) != KEY_ESC )
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
        case ARROW_UP:
            printf("UP\n");
            break;
        case ARROW_DOWN:
            printf("DOWN\n");
            break;
        case ARROW_LEFT:
            printf("LEFT\n");
            break;
        case ARROW_RIGHT:
            printf("RIGHT\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    getchar();   // wait
    return 0;
}
static int get_code(void)
{
    int ch = getch();    // Error happens here
    if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
        ch = 256 + getch();
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: @Vlad http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/getch

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak do you have `conio.h` library installed?

Comment: @Ahmed Jolani: conio.h file is there, but i did not find conio.h (conio.a)library file in lib directory

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak can't you just use `getchar()` I read what `getch()` does, they look the same unless `getch()` does not show the key pressed by the user.

Comment: This must be part of a larger program. Nothing in this code mentions something like drawing a window (which the error implicates!). Also, are you sure your terminal (or GUI) captures those arrow keys?

Comment: @Ahmed Jolani: I have used `getchar()` but it is not responding to arrow keys...

Comment: @Evert: This is not the part of any larger program.. This is the complete program. I don't know why it is showing this problem in Code::Blocks

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak try commenting `puts` please and tell us what happens, sorry I can't do this by my own cause I don't have conio.h installed.

Comment: @Ahmed Jolani:Is there any other way to capture arrow keys?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak Your code runs perfectly fine on my Code Blocks 10.05. May be, by mistake, you are not showing us complete code?

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak I tried to find, but no..

Comment: @Pavan Manjunath: I am also using Code::Block 10.05. and this is the complete code

Comment: @Ahmed Jolani: I have tried with the same (getchar()).. but no result.
But I have tried with getche(). It did work fine with an extra symbol like below 
αRIGHT
`αDOWN
αLEFT
αDOWN
αUP`
You can see an "alpha" symbol before all the printf . Don't know why it is coming

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak check my answer, I hope it work with you :)

Comment: Finally I found the solution `int ch = getche();
    if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
        ch = 256 + getche();`. and putting one `\b` before all `printf`
Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the α came from the `getche()` input, it prompts the user for input and when the user press a key then enter it echos that key on the standard output "screen" and since the arrows are non-printable keys that's what happened you can do something like like this:

```
switch (ch)
        {
        case ARROW_UP:
            printf("\bUP\n");
            break;
        case ARROW_DOWN:
            printf("\bDOWN\n");
            break;
        case ARROW_LEFT:
            printf("\bLEFT\n");
            break;
        case ARROW_RIGHT:
            printf("\bRIGHT\n");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I did exactly the same Thanks A Ton

Answer (score 0):

actually conio.h is not standard header file which is not supported in Code :: Blocks
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library

getch() definition found only in conio.h so it shows error
try scanf to get user input.

Comment: @Jameelopix That's totally irrelevant.

Comment: @AhmedJolani can u state which is irrelevant in my answer

Comment: @Jameelopix how you are going to use scanf to capture keyboard arrows?

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks(MinGW) doesnt have conio.h header file. So you cant use the getch() function.